# export temp from Witty pi 2 to a logfile

Tags: awk, grep

i have installed a witty pi 2 on my RPI3
But i want to export the temp from it to a spcific file

i can run a script called witty.sh and then i need to press 8 or Ctrl + C to quit

```
>>> Current temperature: 33.50°C / 92.3°F
>>> Your system time is: Sat 01 Jul 2017 20:29:46 CEST
>>> Your RTC time is:    Sat 01 Jul 2017 20:29:46 CEST
Now you can:
  1. Write system time to RTC
  2. Write RTC time to system
  3. Synchronize time
  4. Schedule next shutdown [25 15:04:00]
  5. Schedule next startup  [25 15:05:00]
  6. Choose schedule script
  7. Reset data...
  8. Exit
What do you want to do? (1~8)
```

All i want is to export the first line.

I tried

```
sudo ./wittyPi.sh | grep Current | awk '{ print $4 }' > temp.log
```

but it´s ask me for a number and then give the temp in temp.log

Is it possible to insert some extra code to generete Ctrl + C or sometinhg in the end ?

Comment: What happens if you do `echo 8 | sudo ./wittyPi.sh`?

Comment: That helps :)
But when i run it from cronjob, the temp.log i empty.
It works when i run i self in commandline

The permission is 777 on temp.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a here string to provide the input:

```
$ cat tst.sh
echo "Type something:" >&2
read foo
echo "$foo"

$ ./tst.sh <<<stuff | sed 's/u/X/'
Type something:
stXff
```

and if your shell doesn't support here strings then use a here document instead:

```
$ ./tst.sh <<EOF | sed 's/u/X/'
> stuff
> EOF
Type something:
stXff
```

So you'd do (you never need grep when you're using awk):

```
sudo ./wittyPi.sh <<<8 | awk '/Current/{ print $4 }' > temp.log
```

or:

```
sudo ./wittyPi.sh <<<8 | awk 'NR==1{ print $4 }' > temp.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better way is to take a look at the get_temperature() function in the "utilities.sh" file, and see how it is implemented. It only involves some I2C communications.